# how to read echo from dynamically created php file and refresh echo in div

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am refreshing the content of a div with jquery every 10 seconds.
I read the content from a php file named status.php

js and div:

```
 <script>
function autoRefresh_div()
{
  $("#ReloadThis").load("status.php");// a function which will load data   from other file after x seconds
}

setInterval('autoRefresh_div()', 10000); // refresh div after 10 secs
</script>

<div id="ReloadThis"></div>
```

When i put this into my status.php it works fine:

```
$mystatus = 'busy';

echo $mystatus;
```

In the div appears after a couple of seconds: "busy".

When i try to dynamically give the $mystatus a value, it does not wrk anymore:

form:

```
<form method="post" action="status.php">
 <input type="text" name="status"/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and status.php:

```
$mystatus = $_POST['status'];

echo $mystatus;
```

When i open status.php it echoes the value of the input.
But the javascript does not show the echo anymore in the div

Why does this not work when i create the value of $mystatus dynamically?

Comment: You need to save the post value somewhere and load that value when status.php is called by ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every request you make to PHP is a stand alone request. So suppose you have submitted status value using POST, your php script will just remember it for that request only.

So the next time when your jquery tries to request for that value, it will not be there.

You need to store the POST value to session, and then resend the session value each time.

Something like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['status'])) 
     $_SESSION['status'] = $_POST['status'];

if(!empty($_SESSION['status'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['status'];
}
else 
    echo "default";
```

Of course you have to start session before doing this using `session_start();`

Comment: is this the code which should work? because i tried it with session_start(); in front of it but still no result...

Comment: you are right. I have updated my code. So not it's changing session var value on each POST, and if it's not POST request, it's returning session value if it's set or default otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the $_POST['status'] in a session variable as given above or insert into the database.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but they're assuming that you've posted the status once and then want the refresh to return the same value as was previously posted.

However, if you want the refresh to also re-post the current form data, then you just have to include that post data in the `load()` function, like so:

```
$("#ReloadThis").load("status.php", $("form").serialize());
```